# Keep track of changes on the web server files

Tags: web-deployment

To develop a website I use filezilla and notepad ++. It is not an optimal solution as it does not handle the simultaneous modification of the same file. I often need to remember what changes I have made so I can go back.
I use an IIS7 web server.
What is the easiest way to automatically remember file changes on the server so you can discard or confirm them?

Answer (score 0):

I using a apache, and notepad++, filezilla too, when i finish edit file, i save it, and filezilla auto ask em

Comment: Notepad allows you to go back with the changes but if you want to know if other users have modified files on the server?